# In which directory I have to place testng.xml?

Tags: java, maven, testng

I'm doing one project in which I have to perform automation testing.  For this purpose I'm using Testng framework.

I am giving `testng.xml` as input file and some method will consume it, however right now my reader method is not able to detect the file.

In which directory I to place my `testng.xml` file..... and is there any maven specification I have to make in `pom.xml` for detecting that `testng.xml` file is there and they have to read it.

Comment: you should post your code.... your question is no help without knowing what your doing...

Comment: Can you list the directories you're using for your build and the XML files?  Also, when you reference the files, are you using relative or absolute paths?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Using_Suite_XML_Files)?

Comment: Remember to accept this answer if helpful.

Answer (score 6):

> In which directory I to place my testng.xml file.....

I suspect that the `testng.xml` file should be put at the top of your classpath.  If you are using maven then a good place for it would be `src/test/resources/testng.xml`.  See this example:

> [How to call testng.xml file from pom.xml in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533151/how-can-i-call-testng-xml-file-from-pom-xml-in-maven)
>
> is there any maven specification I have to make in pom.xml for detecting that testng.xml file is there and they have to read it.

I'm not 100% sure about this.  In looking at the above example it looks like something like the following is recommended:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
       <suiteXmlFiles>
           <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: thanks! that worked fine for me. But 1 most important thing I've noticed- no matter what folder   testng.xml  is placed, POM.xml should exactly replace its location. And it works :)   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where you put as long as you specify the path in your maven pom.xml under maven-surefire-plugin