# Jenkins not able to pick Test cases

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, testng

I am using an maven project with TestNG, project contains 1 testcase
[image]

When I run maven manually using cmd, test suite gets executed properly. 
mvn test -e

I don't get any errors when I do it manually.

I have configured a jenkins maven project.
I have correctly configured maven & jdk.
I have correctly passed path to pom.xml 
Goal: test -e

Jenkins somehow is not able to run my test case. 
It doesn't find my test cases.

**Pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Jenkin_Demo_Project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Jenkin_Demo_Project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
               <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.48.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

TestNG.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Example test run">
  <test name="StartTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestCase.StartApplication"/>
      </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Please tell me what am i missing, Why jenkin's not able to pick my test case, though manually its working fine. 
I have jenkins installed on my local system. 
Image of jenkin project :
[image]

Jenkins Console Output :

```
Started by user neha1
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitMavenProject
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/nehabedi/Repo1.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/nehabedi/Repo1.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
Setting http proxy: 172.18.65.22:80
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/nehabedi/Repo1.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c63d32391414a2a8368c74fb34733fafc66fc5f6 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f c63d32391414a2a8368c74fb34733fafc66fc5f6
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-list c63d32391414a2a8368c74fb34733fafc66fc5f6 # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
[Jenkin_Demo_Project] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java" -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;D:\apache-maven-3.2.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;D:\apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main D:\apache-maven-3.2.5 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.53.3.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar" 52804
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitMavenProject\Jenkin_Demo_Project\pom.xml clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jenkin_Demo_Project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Jenkin_Demo_Project ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitMavenProject\Jenkin_Demo_Project\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Jenkin_Demo_Project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitMavenProject\Jenkin_Demo_Project\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Jenkin_Demo_Project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitMavenProject\Jenkin_Demo_Project\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Jenkin_Demo_Project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitMavenProject\Jenkin_Demo_Project\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Jenkin_Demo_Project ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (default-test) @ Jenkin_Demo_Project ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitMavenProject\Jenkin_Demo_Project\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: please post the console log of jenkins..are you checking in somewhere.. is the code checked out?

Comment: Hello Neha, were you able to find any solution? Even I'm not getting any error but none of the test cases have started to execute.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance this looks oke. Wondering, is the location of testng.xml right? I would also try to scope of testng dependency to test, like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.9.10</version>
  <test>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am able to execute it using eclipse ( run as maven test) also using command prompt. It works fine only with jenkins its not working.

Comment: What is the error/info you are seeing in the jenkins console? Also, please check, after editing Goals and Options to  -Dtests=src/test/resources/testng.xml test

Comment: skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Dexcom_project\CGM\integration-tests\Jenkin_Demo_Project\src\main\resources.

Comment: I have no where configured to pick "D:\Dexcom_project\CGM\integration-tests\Jenkin_Demo_Project\src\main\resources"path to access the files. In pom.xml i have specified correct path of testng.xml & in testng.xml i have specified location of class containing test cases.

Comment: Wondering, did you see the same problem, after editing the Goals and Options?

Comment: I tried with  MAVEN_OPTS  in build section as -Dtest= testng.xml ( as my testng.xml is located in the project's root folder). it didn't work. I tried with goals as clean install -U  and clean test . It didn't work with that too.

Comment: Not sure, what could be the root cause. You could try using mavne profile like mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533151/how-to-call-testng-xml-file-from-pom-xml-in-maven